# export-cvs from foreach with subfunctions

Tags: powershell

I can't find the right way to look this up on google
I want to list all unified groups in AzureAD; with the amount of members and the owners.
I'd like to output this info to a csv. I can do `get-unifiedgroups |export-csv`

but the problem is those function calls I make to get more info.
What I have at the moment is this:

```
Get-UnifiedGroup | foreach  { 
                Write-Host $($("TEAM: $_  ").PadRight(40)) ; 
                Write-Host "    Members: $($(get-unifiedgrouplinks -Identity $_.DisplayName -LinkType Member).count)";  
                Write-Host "    Adress:  $($_.primarysmtpaddress)" ;
                Write-Host "    Classification:  $($_.Classification)" ;
                Write-host "    Owners:  $(get-unifiedgrouplinks -Identity $_.DisplayName -LinkType Owner) "; 
                Write-host "";
                Write-host "";
            }
```

Comment: Your code does not call the `Get-UnifiedGroupLinks` cmdlet anywhere; it simply outputs the code to console with `Write-Host`..

Comment: I don't know how it's called but $(function) does get evaluated inside a string.

Answer (score 0):

first of all I changed it to output to csv, that's easier
second I just pipe everything to OUT-FILE

```
Get-UnifiedGroup | foreach  { 
        "$($_.displayname) ; $($(get-unifiedgrouplinks -Identity $_.DisplayName -LinkType Member).count) ; $($_.primarysmtpaddress) ;  $($_.Classification) ;  $(get-unifiedgrouplinks -Identity $_.DisplayName -LinkType Owner)" | Out-File $csvlocation -Encoding ascii -Append
    }
```